# How to plot a parametric surface in Python without a coordinate system and with flexible coloring?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graphics, 3d

I need to plot a 3D surface given parametrically:

```
x = x(p1, p2)
y = y(p1, p2)
z = z(p1, p2)
```

In addition to that I would like to have the flexibility to set color for each location on the surface:

```
r = r(p1, p2)
g = g(p1, p2)
b = b(p1, p2)
```

where `r`, `g` and `b` stand for red, green and blue, respectively.

Finally, on the image I do not want to have any coordinate system. There should be just the surface and the pixels, where there is no surface, have to be 100% transparent (possible with png format). If it is possible to get a numpy array representing the image (projection of the surface) without generating an actual image, it would be even better.

I also would like to be able to set the source of light (given by its location).

What would a proper way to approach this problem in Python? What libraries can I use. I found for example [Plotly](https://plot.ly/python/3d-parametric-plots/). I also know that matplotlib can generate parametric surfaces. But I do not know what libraries give the flexibility that I need (setting the color, no coordinate system, source of light).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In matplotlib you can plot surfaces, you can set colors of vertices, you can disable the coordinate system and set light sources. Whether this will give you the desired results, you need to test for yourself.

You may also want to look into [Mayavi](http://code.enthought.com/projects/mayavi/), which works much better when it comes to real 3D applications.

Finally, not related to python but very powerful: [Paraview](http://www.paraview.org)